# Как написать функцию stop в js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть игра змейка, запускается сразу же при нажатии кнопки "начать заново", или при перезагрузке страницы.
Как сделать функцию stop в js, при нажатии на кнопку стоп?

```js
// Настройка «холста»
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// Получаем ширину и высоту элемента canvas
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
// Вычисляем ширину и высоту в ячейках
var blockSize = 10;
var widthInBlocks = width / blockSize;
var heightInBlocks = height / blockSize;
// Устанавливаем счет 0
var score = 0;
// Рисуем рамку
var drawBorder = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "Gray";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, blockSize);
  ctx.fillRect(0, height - blockSize, width, blockSize);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, blockSize, height);
  ctx.fillRect(width - blockSize, 0, blockSize, height);
};
// Выводим счет игры в левом верхнем углу
var drawScore = function() {
  ctx.font = "20px Courier";
  ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
  ctx.textAlign = "left";
  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  ctx.fillText("Счет: " + score, blockSize, blockSize);
};
// Отменяем действие setInterval и печатаем сообщение «Конец игры»
var gameOver = function() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  ctx.font = "60px Courier";
  ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.fillText("Конец игры", width / 2, height / 2);
};
// Рисуем окружность (используя функцию из главы 14)
var circle = function(x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};
// Задаем конструктор Block (ячейка)
var Block = function(col, row) {
  this.col = col;
  this.row = row;
};
// Рисуем квадрат в позиции ячейки
Block.prototype.drawSquare = function(color) {
  var x = this.col * blockSize;
  var y = this.row * blockSize;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, blockSize, blockSize);
};
// Рисуем круг в позиции ячейки
Block.prototype.drawCircle = function(color) {
  var centerX = this.col * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
  var centerY = this.row * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  circle(centerX, centerY, blockSize / 2, true);
};
// Проверяем, находится ли эта ячейка в той же позиции, что и ячейка
// otherBlock
Block.prototype.equal = function(otherBlock) {
  return this.col === otherBlock.col && this.row === otherBlock.row;
};
// Задаем конструктор Snake (змейка)
var Snake = function() {
  this.segments = [
    new Block(7, 5),
    new Block(6, 5),
    new Block(5, 5)
  ];
  this.direction = "right";
  this.nextDirection = "right";
};
// Рисуем квадратик для каждого сегмента тела змейки
Snake.prototype.draw = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    this.segments[i].drawSquare("Blue");
  }
};
// Создаем новую голову и добавляем ее к началу змейки,
// чтобы передвинуть змейку в текущем направлении
Snake.prototype.move = function() {
  var head = this.segments[0];
  var newHead;
  this.direction = this.nextDirection;
  if (this.direction === "right") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col + 1, head.row);
  } else if (this.direction === "down") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row + 1);
  } else if (this.direction === "left") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col - 1, head.row);
  } else if (this.direction === "up") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row - 1);
  }
  if (this.checkCollision(newHead)) {
    gameOver();
    return;
  }
  this.segments.unshift(newHead);
  if (newHead.equal(apple.position)) {
    score++;
    apple.move();
  } else {
    this.segments.pop();
  }
};
// Проверяем, не столкнулась ли змейка со стеной или собственным
// телом
Snake.prototype.checkCollision = function(head) {
  var leftCollision = (head.col === 0);
  var topCollision = (head.row === 0);
  var rightCollision = (head.col === widthInBlocks - 1);
  var bottomCollision = (head.row === heightInBlocks - 1);
  var wallCollision = leftCollision || topCollision || rightCollision || bottomCollision;
  var selfCollision = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    if (head.equal(this.segments[i])) {
      selfCollision = true;
    }
  }
  return wallCollision || selfCollision;
};
// Задаем следующее направление движения змейки на основе нажатой
// клавиши
Snake.prototype.setDirection = function(newDirection) {
  if (this.direction === "up" && newDirection === "down") {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === "right" && newDirection === "left") {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === "down" && newDirection === "up") {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === "left" && newDirection === "right") {
    return;
  }
  this.nextDirection = newDirection;
};
// Задаем конструктор Apple (яблоко)
var Apple = function() {
  this.position = new Block(10, 10);
};
// Рисуем кружок в позиции яблока
Apple.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.position.drawCircle("LimeGreen");
};
// Перемещаем яблоко в случайную позицию
Apple.prototype.move = function() {
  var randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * (widthInBlocks - 2)) + 1;
  var randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * (heightInBlocks - 2)) + 1;
  this.position = new Block(randomCol, randomRow);
};
// Создаем объект-змейку и объект-яблоко
var snake = new Snake();
var apple = new Apple();
// Запускаем функцию анимации через setInterval
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  drawScore();
  snake.move();
  snake.draw();
  apple.draw();
  drawBorder();
}, 100);
// Преобразуем коды клавиш в направления
var directions = {
  37: "left",
  38: "up",
  39: "right",
  40: "down"
};
// Задаем обработчик события keydown (клавиши-стрелки)
$("body").keydown(function(event) {
  var newDirection = directions[event.keyCode];
  if (newDirection !== undefined) {
    snake.setDirection(newDirection);
  }
});

function restart() {
  location.reload();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="restart()">Начать заново</button>
<button onclick="stopFunction()">Стоп игра</button>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88708/discussion-on-question-by-lausa----stop--js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function stopFunction() {
  intervalId = clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```

```js
// Настройка «холста»
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// Получаем ширину и высоту элемента canvas
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
// Вычисляем ширину и высоту в ячейках
var blockSize = 10;
var widthInBlocks = width / blockSize;
var heightInBlocks = height / blockSize;
// Устанавливаем счет 0
var score = 0;
// Рисуем рамку
var drawBorder = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "Gray";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, blockSize);
  ctx.fillRect(0, height - blockSize, width, blockSize);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, blockSize, height);
  ctx.fillRect(width - blockSize, 0, blockSize, height);
};
// Выводим счет игры в левом верхнем углу
var drawScore = function() {
  ctx.font = "20px Courier";
  ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
  ctx.textAlign = "left";
  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  ctx.fillText("Счет: " + score, blockSize, blockSize);
};
// Отменяем действие setInterval и печатаем сообщение «Конец игры»
var gameOver = function() {
  intervalId = clearInterval(intervalId);
  ctx.font = "60px Courier";
  ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.fillText("Конец игры", width / 2, height / 2);
};
// Рисуем окружность (используя функцию из главы 14)
var circle = function(x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};
// Задаем конструктор Block (ячейка)
var Block = function(col, row) {
  this.col = col;
  this.row = row;
};
// Рисуем квадрат в позиции ячейки
Block.prototype.drawSquare = function(color) {
  var x = this.col * blockSize;
  var y = this.row * blockSize;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, blockSize, blockSize);
};
// Рисуем круг в позиции ячейки
Block.prototype.drawCircle = function(color) {
  var centerX = this.col * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
  var centerY = this.row * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  circle(centerX, centerY, blockSize / 2, true);
};
// Проверяем, находится ли эта ячейка в той же позиции, что и ячейка
// otherBlock
Block.prototype.equal = function(otherBlock) {
  return this.col === otherBlock.col && this.row === otherBlock.row;
};
// Задаем конструктор Snake (змейка)
var Snake = function() {
  this.segments = [
    new Block(7, 5),
    new Block(6, 5),
    new Block(5, 5)
  ];
  this.direction = "right";
  this.nextDirection = "right";
};
// Рисуем квадратик для каждого сегмента тела змейки
Snake.prototype.draw = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    this.segments[i].drawSquare("Blue");
  }
};
// Создаем новую голову и добавляем ее к началу змейки,
// чтобы передвинуть змейку в текущем направлении
Snake.prototype.move = function() {
  var head = this.segments[0];
  var newHead;
  this.direction = this.nextDirection;
  if (this.direction === "right") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col + 1, head.row);
  } else if (this.direction === "down") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row + 1);
  } else if (this.direction === "left") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col - 1, head.row);
  } else if (this.direction === "up") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row - 1);
  }
  if (this.checkCollision(newHead)) {
    gameOver();
    return;
  }
  this.segments.unshift(newHead);
  if (newHead.equal(apple.position)) {
    score++;
    apple.move();
  } else {
    this.segments.pop();
  }
};
// Проверяем, не столкнулась ли змейка со стеной или собственным
// телом
Snake.prototype.checkCollision = function(head) {
  var leftCollision = (head.col === 0);
  var topCollision = (head.row === 0);
  var rightCollision = (head.col === widthInBlocks - 1);
  var bottomCollision = (head.row === heightInBlocks - 1);
  var wallCollision = leftCollision || topCollision || rightCollision || bottomCollision;
  var selfCollision = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    if (head.equal(this.segments[i])) {
      selfCollision = true;
    }
  }
  return wallCollision || selfCollision;
};
// Задаем следующее направление движения змейки на основе нажатой
// клавиши
Snake.prototype.setDirection = function(newDirection) {
  if (this.direction === "up" && newDirection === "down") {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === "right" && newDirection === "left") {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === "down" && newDirection === "up") {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === "left" && newDirection === "right") {
    return;
  }
  this.nextDirection = newDirection;
};
// Задаем конструктор Apple (яблоко)
var Apple = function() {
  this.position = new Block(10, 10);
};
// Рисуем кружок в позиции яблока
Apple.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.position.drawCircle("LimeGreen");
};
// Перемещаем яблоко в случайную позицию
Apple.prototype.move = function() {
  var randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * (widthInBlocks - 2)) + 1;
  var randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * (heightInBlocks - 2)) + 1;
  this.position = new Block(randomCol, randomRow);
};
// Создаем объект-змейку и объект-яблоко
var snake = new Snake();
var apple = new Apple();

// Преобразуем коды клавиш в направления
var directions = {
  37: "left",
  38: "up",
  39: "right",
  40: "down"
};
// Задаем обработчик события keydown (клавиши-стрелки)
$("body").keydown(function(event) {
  var newDirection = directions[event.keyCode];
  if (newDirection !== undefined) {
    snake.setDirection(newDirection);
  }
});

function restart() {
  location.reload();
}

function stopFunction() {
  intervalId = clearInterval(intervalId);
}

// Запускаем функцию анимации через setInterval
var intervalId;

function continueFunction() {
  if (intervalId)
    return;
  intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    drawScore();
    snake.move();
    snake.draw();
    apple.draw();
    drawBorder();
  }, 100);
}
continueFunction();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="restart()">Начать заново</button>
<button onclick="stopFunction()">Стоп игра</button>
<button onclick="continueFunction()">Продолжить игру</button>
```